# How can I to go to step definition file in VS Code using cypress and BDD

Tags: visual-studio-code, cucumber, cypress, bdd

I am using windows 11, VS Code, cypres,bdd and cucumber gherkin (full support) extension. I am not able to go to step definition file from feature file. below is my folder structure :

[image]

I have tried below solutions :

1: Go to file > preference > setting > workspace > setting.json
[image]

Here if I hover over highlighted error it says - No steps files foundcucumberautocomplete. Tried giving path through work directory/cypress.

2: Go to extension > click on setting for cucumber gherkin (full support) > Extension setting > edit in setting.json
[image]

Here it shows no error, if i go to any feature file - it says was unable to find step for cucumberautocomplete
[image]

I tried restarting but nothing is working. Can someone please help me with solution to this.
Thanks !!